Detect token at processed transaction level
I believe it's not possible with Raydium to detect the token a wallet is swapping for, at the processed level, but rather only at confirmed. Claude is telling me it IS possible on pump.fun. Anyone have any insight?

Please check this. https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/18016/27980
